# Reverse an associative array with preserving keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I spent half an hour but I haven't found a solution.

Following example of an array:

```
array(14) {
  ["label_text"]=> string(10) "Label text"
  ["e-mail"]=> string(6) "E-Mail"
  ["company"]=> string(7) "Company"
  ["last_name"]=> string(9) "Last name"
  ["first_name"]=> string(10) "First name"
}
```

What I want to do is just reverse the elements, so that the result is this:

```
array(14) {
  ["first_name"]=> string(10) "First name"
  ["last_name"]=> string(9) "Last name"
  ["company"]=> string(7) "Company"
  ["e-mail"]=> string(6) "E-Mail"
  ["label_text"]=> string(10) "Label text"
}
```

There must be a native php for this, but I think I'm blind. I just don't know which function to use.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use [array_reverse()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

> array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array with the order of the
>   elements reversed.

Note: make sure you read the documentation about the 2nd argument of said function.

Comment: Make sure you read the docs, too ;) 'Non-numeric keys are not affected by this setting and will always be preserved.'

Comment: what is the use of keeping array keys preserved in this way ?

Comment: probably no use, it's just something that was easy to implement and describe. PHP doesn't seem to change their order when it inserts things into an array. Just do a foreach statement and insert into a new array

Answer (score 5):

What about the reverse function **array_reverse** ?

```
$reversed = array_reverse($array, true);
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function:

```
$new_array = array_reverse($old_array);
```

Comment: Yes it will. They're not numeric keys. From the docs: *Non-numeric keys are not affected by this setting and will always be preserved.*

Comment: That's not correct. Non-numeric assoc Arrays are not effected by this option.

Answer (score -1):

Just do it like this:

```
$reversed = array_combine(
   array_reverse(array_keys($arr)),
   array_reverse(array_values($arr))
);
```